# Backbone model.save() reports error in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js

information:

- backbone version: 1.0.0
- jQuery version: v1.10.2
- chrome version
  29.0.1547.65
- running the site locally using an Apache server

I am creating a simple app to learn how to use backbone that creates a todo list (following Jeffery Way's 'connected to the backbone' tutorials). I have implemented the restful API using Laravel 4 put when I try to save a model (tasks in this case)   using tasks.save() chrome reports an error in jQuery on line 8706.

When i check my database the record has indeed been updated but the success function does not fire, but when i run the same code in safari everything is fine.

```
task.save(null, {success:function(){console.log('item saved to database')}});
```

So my question is: Is this a bug or should i have set something up before hand.

(I have seen some similar questions to this but could see none where people were stating that jQuery return an error)

EDIT: The error I am getting

```
GET http://localhost:8888/todo/public/tasks/1  jquery.js:8706

 - send jquery.js:8706 jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:8136 
 - Backbone.ajax backbone.js:1202 
 - Backbone.sync backbone.js:1185
 - _.extend.sync backbone.js:289
 - _.extend.save backbone.js:492 
 - (anonymous function) 
 - InjectedScript._evaluateOn
 - InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
 - InjectedScript.evaluate
```

EDIT: ok now i feel stupid, I set my laravel up using the way/generator and used scaffolding which returns views and not models. Once i edited the controllers update function to return the model and not a view chrome was happy, weird though that safari did not have a problem with this though and was happy to accept the model was updated as a success

(bit new to stack overflow should i leave this question here or should i remove it?)

Comment: I have added the error to the question now, still researching around the place and still can;t find anyone who quotes that jQuery is being returned as the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok now i feel stupid, I set my laravel up using the way/generator and used scaffolding which returns views and not models. Once i edited the controllers update function to return the model and not a view chrome was happy, weird though that safari did not have a problem with this though and was happy to accept the model was updated as a success

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error appears when backbone tries to save newly created model before the server response thus model doesn't have an id.
In that case you have to wait for the server response:

`model.save({your: data}, {wait: true})`